# Find $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}$$\int_0^n(1 + \frac{-x}{n})^n\cos(\frac{x}{\sqrt{n}})e^{x/2}dx$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Find $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}$$\int_0^n(1 + \frac{-x}{n})^n\cos(\frac{x}{\sqrt{n}})e^{x/2}dx$

I want to use dominated convergence theorem obviously.  However, not sure how to dominate it.  Clearly $(1 + \frac{-x}{n})^n \rightarrow e^{-x}$.

Any suggestions?  Thanks.

Comment: Try finding a $c > \frac{1}{2}$ such that $$\left( 1 - \frac{x}{n}\right)^n \leqslant e^{-cx}$$ for $0 \leqslant x \leqslant n$.

Comment: Not seeing how to do this.

Comment: Hint: The exponential function is convex.

Answer (score 1):

If we set
$$ I_n = \int_{0}^{n}\left(1-\frac{x}{n}\right)^n\cos\frac{x}{\sqrt n}e^{x/2}dx$$
we obviously have:
$$ I_n \leq \int_{0}^{n}\cos\frac{x}{\sqrt{n}}e^{-x/2}dx\leq \int_{0}^{\sqrt{n}}\cos\frac{x}{\sqrt n}e^{-x/2}dx+(n-\sqrt{n}) e^{-\sqrt{n}/2}\leq 2+o(1),$$
while:
$$ \left|I_n-\int_{0}^{n}\cos\frac{x}{\sqrt{n}}e^{-x/2}dx\right|\leq 2o(1)+\int_{0}^{\sqrt{n}}\left (e^{-\xi}-\left(1-\frac{\xi}{n}\right)^n\right)e^{\xi/2}d\xi$$
is bounded by:
$$2o(1)+C\cdot\int_{0}^{\sqrt{n}}\frac{\xi^2}{2n}\exp\left(\frac{\xi}{2}-\frac{(n-1)}{n}\xi\right)d\xi=o(1)+O(1/n) = o(1)$$
due to the inequality:
$$ A\geq B\geq 0\quad\Rightarrow\quad A^n-B^n \leq n(A-B)A^{n-1}.$$
Hence we have:
$$ I_n-2 = o(1)$$
and the limit is just $2$ by squeezing.

Comment: How is the first inequality obvious?  I don't see how $I_n≤\int_0^ncos\frac{x}{n^{0.5}}e^{−x/2}dx$

Comment: $(1-\frac{x}{n})^n\leq e^{-x}$.

Comment: How do you prove that?  I don't see it for some reason.

Comment: It is the Bernoulli inequality: for any $x$ such that $|x|\leq n$, $\left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)^n\leq e^x.$ It just follows from the concavity of the logarithm.

Comment: All I am getting is that $(1 - \frac{x}{n})^n \geq 1 - x$.